# toFixed after using reduce method JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, tofixed

I`m maping through an array and reducing 50 items to 1 - their sum. That 50 items are float precision numbers. Please help, I don`t understand where in that map I should put toFixed(2), to get proper summaryIncome property instead something like this: 39990,89999999999913.

```
var data = [
  {id: 1, incomes: [{value:1}, {value: 2}]}, 
  {id: 2, incomes: [{value:2}, {value: 3}]}],
  ...
]

var summary = data.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  summaryIncome: item.incomes.reduce((acc, income) =>
    acc += income.value, 0)
}));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To keep the sum accurate, call `toFixed` after summing up all the `value`s:

```js
var data = [
  {id: 1, incomes: [{value: 0.1}, {value: 0.2}]}, 
  {id: 2, incomes: [{value:2}, {value: 3}]},
]

var summary = data.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  summaryIncome: item.incomes.reduce((acc, income) => acc + income.value, 0).toFixed(2)
}));
console.log(summary);
```

To [only put decimal points if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary):

```js
var data = [
  {id: 1, incomes: [{value: 0.1}, {value: 0.2}]}, 
  {id: 2, incomes: [{value:2}, {value: 3}]},
]

var summary = data.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  summaryIncome: (() => {
    const trueSum = item.incomes.reduce((acc, income) => acc + income.value, 0);
    return Number.isInteger(trueSum) ? String(trueSum) : trueSum.toFixed(2);
  })()
}));
console.log(summary);
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, man You are my saviour. I thought that i`ve tried that option. Many thanks.